# Why is the setInterval task executed slower than the setTimeout task in the JavaScript environment?

Tags: javascript, timer, settimeout, setinterval, event-loop

As we all know, the `setInterval` and `setTimeout` tasks are macrotasks in JavaScript Event Loop;
Whereas, after running some tests I find it seems that `setTimeout` has more priority than `setInterval`, so what's the reason for this?

### codes

1. `setTimeout` task before `setInterval` task

```js
setTimeout(() => {
  console.log(`4`);
});

let id = setInterval(() => {
  console.log(`5`);
  clearInterval(id);
});

Promise.resolve().then(() => console.log(`2`));

queueMicrotask(() => {
  console.log(`3`);
});

console.log(`1`);

/*
1
2

3
4
5
*/
```

[image]

2. `setInterval` task before `setTimeout` task

```js
let id = setInterval(() => {
  console.log(`5`);
  clearInterval(id);
});

setTimeout(() => {
  console.log(`4`);
});

Promise.resolve().then(() => console.log(`2`));

queueMicrotask(() => {
  console.log(`3`);
});

console.log(`1`);

/*
1
2

3
4
5
*/
```

[image]

I've read some API docs but still can't get to the under hood of this.

> test environment

1. Google Chrome Version 110.0.5481.177 (Official Build) (x86_64)
2. Node.js v18.12.0

[image]

### docs

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTML_DOM_API/Microtask_guide

https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/timers-and-user-prompts.html

Answer (score 1):

For Chrome, that's a bug. The tasks are to be queued on the same timer task queue and are expected to fire in the queued order. There is no place for any task prioritization in here.

I did open [CRBUG#1421612](https://crbug.com/1421612).

If you want links, both [`setTimeout`](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/timers-and-user-prompts.html#dom-settimeout) and [`setInterval`](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/timers-and-user-prompts.html#dom-setinterval) call the same [timer initialization steps](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/timers-and-user-prompts.html#timer-initialisation-steps), which at step 13 asks to [run steps after a timeout](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/timers-and-user-prompts.html#run-steps-after-a-timeout), to queue a task on the [timer task source](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/timers-and-user-prompts.html#timer-task-source). To [run steps after a timeout](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/timers-and-user-prompts.html#run-steps-after-a-timeout) consists in waiting that *milliseconds* ms have passed and then execute the passed *completionSteps*, but it has this particular step:

> Wait until any invocations of this algorithm that had the same *global* and *orderingIdentifier*, that started before this one, and whose *milliseconds* is equal to or less than this one's, have completed.

In our case, the *global* is obviously the same, and *orderingIdentifier* is the string `"setTimeout/setInterval"` in both cases, and *milliseconds* [is `0`](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/webappapis.html#windoworworkerglobalscope-mixin:dom-settimeout).
So we ought to have our *completionSteps* fired in the same order as we queued them. And given these *completionSteps* do [queue a global task](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/webappapis.html#queue-a-global-task) on the same task-source, our JS callbacks ought to be performed in that same order.

The [apparent culprit](https://crbug.com/402694) is an active work that's done to remove a 1ms minimal *milliseconds* limit that Chrome has on timers since the beginning. It seems that while removing that limit they made `setTimeout()` and `setInterval()` use different paths.
And so this means that using any other value than `0` for *milliseconds* will make it behave as expected:

```js
const pre = document.querySelector(".actual pre");
const id1 = setInterval(() => {
  pre.textContent += "setInterval()\n";
  pre.style.color = "red";
  clearInterval(id1);
}, 1); // non-zero timeout
const id2 = setTimeout(() => {
  pre.textContent += "setTimeout()\n";
  pre.style.color = "green";
}, 1); // non-zero timeout (same)
```

```css
.expected pre { color: green };
```

```html
<div class="expected">
  <h4>Expected</h4>
  <pre>setInterval()
setTimeout()
</pre>
</div>
<div class="actual">
  <h4>Actual</h4>
  <pre></pre>
</div>
```

---

Note that Node is not following the HTML specs exactly regarding the timers and event loop processing, so they are free to do as they want and it's generally not a good idea to compare against it to see if a browser is behaving correctly. Prefer to use another vendor instead.

Comment: safari is the same way

Comment: @DanielA.White indeed, they're wrong too, I opened https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=253423

Answer (score 0):

I believe it is up to the browser implementation, and it would be more correct to say that `setInterval` is probably not slower but just lower in priority queue than `setTimeout`, or it could be that Chrome's implementation puts `setTimeout` in the event loop faster than `setInterval`. What's interesting is if you run the same code in the Mozilla Firefox you will notice that the interval is executed first and timeout is second just like you expected (at least this is the case on my machine). Your best bet would be looking into [V8 source code](https://github.com/v8/v8) and maybe looking into [libevent](https://libevent.org/) library that Chromium uses for event loop, but I doubt that you need to dig that deep.

Comment:  thank you for your time. I'll try to figure it out as your suggested.